# Why is Istanbul with Qunit able to see my source files, but does not measure their coverage?

Tags: javascript, testing, code-coverage, qunit, nyc

I’m creating [some modules](https://github.com/Beakerboy/Threejs-Geometries/tree/coverage) to work with three-js and since that project uses Qunit, I’m sticking with that.

Qunit is running my test scripts correctly. I read a couple quick tutorials on coverage testing with qunit, and Istanbul (nyc) seems to be recommended. I added `"nyc": "*"`, to my devDependencies, and changed my test script to be `"test": "nyc qunit"`.
I now see a coverage report, but nyc is not measuring any coverage, and not listing any files. If I change the test script to `"test": "nyc --all qunit"` the report shows that it now does see all my source files, but says all the lines are uncovered.
Is there another step I need to ensure nyc can measure coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to the drop-in replacement bcoe/c8 and it started to work. Nyc seems to no longer be in development.